# why does this simple in Kotlin code throw a NumberFormatExeption?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When I run this simple code in Kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val a = readln().toInt()
    val b = readln().toInt()
    println(a+b)
}
```

It throws a NumberFormatExeption:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:678)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:784)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:4)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

This is an [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btypg.png) of the given input and the error.

But once I separate the two inputs, for example with a println, the code works.

```
fun main() {
    println("Enter a")
    val a = readln().toInt()
    println("Enter b")
    val b = readln().toInt()
    println(a+b)
}
```

This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNLea.png) of the input and that it works.

Any idea why this occurs, and if so, how to fix it?

Comment: In case you are wondering why you are downvoted: [How to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And more specifically this [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide error messages and code *textually* (with code blocks) instead of via screenshots. There are many reasons why screenshots are bad for this. You can of course add screenshots to show IDE issues, but primarily add the code so it's searchable and people can try it on their side without typing everything. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1540818

Comment: @Alex.T it seems I was too slow to type all this :D

Comment: Sorry for the screen shots, I tried to add the code blocks

Comment: @Hicham you can have screenshots, there is no reason to remove them (I've added them back). In fact, the first ss is beneficial, since it shows how you give the input. The issue was that there was no actual code for us to see directly. If I would have wanted to run that code, I would have to write it from the photo, which not everybody that might know the answer has time to do. Also, if another person has the same issue as you, when they search with their code, this answer would never show up. Also, that image service, might die next month, and the code would be lost forever.

Comment: Now for the actual issue. I've run both scenarios in my IDE, both work fine for me. Can you confirm that you are doing the same thing in both? As in: enter number directly, then pressing enter only? Without spaces or any other thing. If yes, could you tell us your kotlin version and maybe the IDE version?

Comment: hi @Alex.T, thank you for checking and for the clarifications on the screen shots :) . yes it's the same code with the same inputs, I've did some searching and what I understood is that it's a problem with Intelejji Idea. it seems that when ever there is tow inputs it miss reads the second one as an empty string, it's like you hit enter twice.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA™ Community 2022.1.1 as the kotlin versioni think i have the latest 221-1.7.10